# Fancybox won't load inline html - but works fine with text content

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I have a problem with fancybox. It loads text content fine, but it won't load html content at all:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.group").fancybox();
    });
</script>
<a class='group' href='#eventInfo1161a'>161</a>
<div style='display: none;'>
    <div id='eventInfo1161a' style='display: block;' class='textDark'>
        <div class='eventItem'>
            <h3 class='eventItemHeader'>
                Sjov event</h3>
            <div class='eventType'>
                Offentlig</div>
            <div class='eventStart'>
                Kl.:10:00</div>
            <div class='eventDuration'>
                1,5 timer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I enter some text content in the div with id 'eventInfo1161a' - it loads perfectly - what I'm I missing here?

Comment: I had the same problem with fancybox and some other lightbox and ended up using popup box instead of lightbox. also most of them doesn't render external CSS and Javascript properly.

Comment: Oh boy... It was such a stupid mistake on my behalf!

Someplace in my styling I set .eventItem = display:none;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy... It was such a stupid mistake on my behalf! Someplace in my styling I set .eventItem = display:none;

So look for overrides in Your CSS :-(